# Best method for comment section associated with different images?

Tags: posts, comments, comment-meta, wp-comment-query

I would like to create a site where users can upload images and then all users can make comments associated with this image. Because users can upload multiple images I cannot make a new wordpress page for each image. I figured I would have a single page that would use $_GET from the url to figure out which image to show. But now I need to know how to populate the comments associate with that image and when a user comments to make sure the new comment will be assign to that image.

Is it possible to make a list of comments (based on selected post_id) and displaying them through the wordpress comment template (comments_template()) or another comment plugin so I could hopeful avoid having to manually code all the comment features.

I was originally trying to assign comment meta data when someone posts but then I was having a hard time having only comments with the appropriate meta data populate. It would show the correct comments but the "Total" comment number would still be all comments, even those without the correct comment meta value.

I was also thinking I should try to manually assign the post_id but I couldn't find an easy way to manually assign and then manually populate the comments based on post_id.

Can someone help me with finding the best method to accomplish this? I've been looking pretty hard for the past couple days and would appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you.